# Import Chrome bookmarks in to Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, bookmarks

How do I import my Chrome (35.0.1916.153) bookmarks in to Safari (7.0.4)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Exporting Your Chrome Bookmarks

Chrome stores bookmarks in a non-HTML format so you need to export them first before you can import them in to Safari.

1. Select `Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager` from the menu bar in Chrome
2. In the Bookmark Manager UI select `Organize > Export Bookmarks to HTML File...`
3. Select a location to save the file (I suggest `Desktop`) in the File window dialog and click the `Save` button

### Import the Exported Bookmarks in to Safari

1. In Safari select `File > Import Bookmarks...` from the menu bar
2. Navigate to the folder where you saved the exported HTML bookmarks file, select the file and press the `Import` button

Your bookmarks will be imported in to a bookmark folder named `imported <date of import>`. For example, on the day of writing this answer, my imported bookmarks were placed in a bookmark folder named `imported 6/22/14`. You can organize your bookmarks in Safari by selecting `Bookmarks > Edit Bookmarks` to open the bookmark editing interface in a tab. Move and re-arrange your imported bookmarks to suit your needs.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Chrome can import bookmarks directly from Safari; too bad it doesn't work the other way also.

Comment: See the answer below - the new Safari 8 has an option for importing from Chrome.

Answer (score 33):

[image: Safari 8: File » Import From]

Just noting that Safari 8 has an option to import directly from Chrome. In Safari, select `File > Import From` from menu bar.

Comment: On a related note, Click on `Chrome > Import Bookmarks and Settings` to import in to Chrome.

Comment: And it does it without creating duplicates! :)

Comment: I realized this option didn't appear for me because I'm using Chrome Canary... In this case I still had to export bookmarks to a file and then import from Safari.

Comment: The favicon is missed....