# How to keep Chrome bookmarks in-sync with Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome

I use Chrome mostly and bookmark often. I would like these bookmarks automatically synched into Safari. Is this possible?s

Comment: This isn't possible. Just pick one browser, that would be my advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153860/37413

Comment: Maybe try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-bookmarks/fkepacicchenbjecpbpbclokcabebhah?hl=en

Comment: I use BookMacster by Sheep Systems on my main Mac. I then turn on Google's sync and iCloud sync. Everything stays synced. All the time. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Kent, I just want to say thanks for your suggestion of BookMacster. I've been looking for an alternative to Xmarks forever since it's been very buggy and essentially stopped working. BookMacster works great.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify the previous answer.

**Known issues with Xmarks+Chrome+Safari**

I would like to add some remarks about [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com). The use of Xmarks for Safari and Chrome works mostly very well, but in some case, you can encounter conflicts issues.

**Context**

If you enable Chrome bookmarks synchronisation and if Xmarks plugin is in automatic sync mode (default setting), some conflicts can appear:

- all your bookmarks folder will appear in double.
- One will be empty, the other contains the bookmarks.

It can be boring to fix that kind of issue manually... Especially when you have a lot of bookmarks.

**Hack/Solution**

The only solution I have found is to:

- Keep using Google Chrome synchronisation (bookmarks, plug-in and whatever you want).
- Disable the automatic mode of Xmarks plugin (both on Safari and Chrome).
- Then, each time you add a bookmark into safari or chrome think to overwrite Xmarks server with "upload" (see Xmarks advanced settings) and then, download the new bookmarks via "download". (*the image below is an Xmarks for Safari screenshot - You have almost the same panel in Chrome Xmarks plugin*).

**Conclusion**

Of course, that trick doesn't make your life easier and is impossible to use when you want to use Safari and Chrome in the same time (too many upload/download to do).

[image: Xmarks for Safari screenshot]

Comment: Are those issues still present in the latest version?

Comment: I have no idea, I have stopped using Safari, however, I presume it's still the case.

Comment: Xmarks is awful and still broken. I've switched to Bookmacster and it's working great

Comment: XMarks is closing up shop on 4/30/18 which is longer than I expected them to ever last.

Answer (score 2):

The only really reliable way to sync between two browsers like Chrome and Safari is to export the bookmarks from the source browser, delete all of the bookmarks in the target browser, and then import. There isn't really a way to "sync" them, per se. This will at least allow you to keep your bookmarks updated, but that's about all you're going to get reliably.

Sadly, with XMarks gone as of 4/30/18, there is no longer a feasible multi-browser sync solution that actually works. Since all of the cross-browser sync extensions are faulty, this is really the only safe way on MacOS.

If you have a Windows host, the iCloud app actually does support sync with other local Windows browsers so if you happen to have a Windows VM or host about your can have it handle this, according to [this article](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/sync-safari-bookmarks-with-chrome-firefox) but I have not tried this yet.

In lieu a on-line sync tool that works and doesn't collide with Safari sync (which is needed for sync to IOS) it seems like the best approach would be to write a script to sync/merge/deduplicate bookmarks between the bookmarks settings of two or three different browsers. Gone are the days where bookmarks used to be saved in a single HTML file but it shouldn't be too hard to handle this as text without having to maintain a third-party database of bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Unfortunately, Xmarks was shut down, so it is no longer an option.

---

You can use [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) to easily sync bookmarks between most desktop browsers, including Google Chrome and Safari.

iOS devices cannot directly sync their native Safari bookmarks with Xmarks, but if you set up Chrome and Safari on your Mac to sync with Xmarks, and turn on iCloud Safari syncing for both your Mac and your iOS device(s), then your iOS Safari bookmarks will be indirectly synced with the ones in Chrome on your Mac.

Comment: Be advised that i will occasionally duplicate your bookmarks, if the chrome native sync is enable, with normally is and it's very useful to keep your chrome on Android linked with chrome on desktop. I gave up on marks because of this. You may pay the premium feature to sync android also. That may work

Comment: is Xmarks dead? the link is...

Comment: Yes, Xmarks was shut down in May 2018. https://xmarksalternatives.com

Answer (score 0):

Don't even bother installing iCloud bookmarks extension for Chrome. It works terribly and will screw up your bookmarks. The only solution I found is to use Xmarks, but it's imperfect, and I often check if Apple updated their Chrome extension to fix their issues. Xmarks works, but deleting bookmarks from Chrome doesn't work if you also have iCloud bookmark sync enabled. They will just pop back up sometime later. You may not need iCloud bookmark sync, but if you have an iOS device you do. The only way to delete a bookmark is to do it from OSX/iOS. You may have to do this several times.

Comment: Furthermore iCloud bookmarks extension only works for Windows OS and not if you want to use Chrome at macOS.