# I'm tinkering with my Safari Bookmarks and want to better understand what's between me and syncing them with my Chrome Bookmarks

Tags: safari, google-chrome, bookmarks

In `/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` I see a "Bookmarks" & "Bookmarks.bak" file. They both appear to have the same or similar data—but what are the differences?

Please let me know if this is the wrong place for this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242787/how-to-keep-chrome-bookmarks-in-sync-with-safari

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks, but unless I'm missing something there, it does not (Xmarks was discontinued, other options seem to be, more or less, "don't". Haha

Comment: Which is basically saying, "there isn't anything that allows this." Unless you are syncing Chrome bookmarks on Windows to Safari bookmarks on the Mac. I think I noticed that iCloud will do that.